# Kotlin Access Item From Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to Kotlin.  I created a blank activity, added a SeekBar, and I was able to override the methods for it to get the functionality that I wanted.  However, if I create a tabbed activity, I am unable to do so when using the same code.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to access an item in a fragment.

I modified my gradle build to include `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

I added a SeekBar and TextView to fragment_main.xml

```
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/strandsSpeed"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="1023"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/strandsSpeed"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="173dp" />
```

I modified onCreate() in PlaceholderFragment.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        strandsSpeed?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(strandsSpeed: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {}

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(strandsSpeed: SeekBar) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(strandsSpeed: SeekBar) {
                textView.text = getString(R.string.test)
            }
        })
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }
    }
```

I tried this same code in MainActivity.kt.  No results.  I also tried a toast in MainActivity.kt.  No results.  The code works fine without the fragment.  Also no results when overriding onProgressChanged().  My guess is it is due to strandsSpeed and textView currently being in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `setOnSeekBarListener()` to `onCreateView()` and utilized the inflater:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_strands, container, false)
    inf.strandsSpeed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(strandsSpeed: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            txtView.text = progress.toString()
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(strandsSpeed: SeekBar) {}

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(strandsSpeed: SeekBar) {}
    })
    return inf
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits to keep me within the guidelines, @double-beep.